# Magento 2: Set robots noindex on layered navigation results

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

How can I set robots :

```
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
```

for layered navigation results in Magento 2?

I have searched the internet but there is no information to be found for this pretty important feature.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved creating a new module with an Observer with this code

```
protected $request;
protected $stateFilter;
protected $layoutFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $layoutFactory
    \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State $stateFilter
) {
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->stateFilter = $stateFilter;
    $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
}

public function execute(Observer $observer) {
    $selectedFilters = $this->stateFilter->getActiveFilters();
    if(count($selectedFilters) > 0) {
        $this->layoutFactory->setRobots('NOINDEX,FOLLOW');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Michele,

can you please provide more of your patch such as which event, or provide the entire module. I don't have enough information to create a solution based on the information you provided. I had to create an answer because I am not allowed to comment.